# VST effects in Windows

Tags: windows

How can I apply VST effects to all audio output from my PC?

I'm using the 32 bit version of Windows 7. I've checked all the sound-related options but there's nothing there that let's me load a VST...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally VST plugins are only used inside another program such as a sequencer (cubase for instance). As for applying them to the whole output of your pc, this isn't really something i've come across. On mac I have come across apps that would you let you add effects to your main output such as reverb and equalization but these are stand-alone apps and not VST plugins.